# Jupyterlab tab completion isn't giving useful recommendations

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I don't think things were like this before.

Say I wanted to choose a directory. I would write:

```
"/home/"
```

and hit tab. recommendations are the following:

[image]

Not very useful. More useful would have been options for the next directory in the path "/..James/" which is all the way at the bottom.

I don't think it was like this before. Is there something I could change to get recommendations to be useful again?